# What is exact difference between "I got it done" & "I had it done"?

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I referred [I had something done vs I got something done](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54939/i-had-something-done-vs-i-got-something-done). 
But
While watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vF9c5RE6c7c) video, At **1:07** found it is used "*I got my plastic surgery done in Mexico*", which according to answer in above link means "*I had done plastic surgery on my own in Mexico*".

Confused?

Comment: I don't see why do you think it means "I had done plastic surgery **on my own** in Mexico"..

Comment: @TRomano, CopperKettle  Answer in question I referred, says that  ""Got it done" usually means that the speaker carried the action himself." Made me me think that way.

Comment: But FumbleFingers **[said](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54939/i-had-something-done-vs-i-got-something-done#comment103672_54939)** there in comments: "**to get it done** implies nothing about whether it'll be done by you or someone else"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I got it done* can mean either:

**I had someone do it for me**

or

**I managed to complete it.**

> I got my homework done before class this morning.
>
> I got a cavity in my molar filled.
>
> She got her hair done in an updo.