# "I had barber cut my hair." "I got the barber to have my hair cut."

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one's correct? If there's anything wrong with either of these two sentences, please correct it.

1. I had barber cut my hair.
2. I got the barber to have my hair cut.

Comment: (1) needs an article before _barber_. _You_ had your hair cut, the barber cut it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I had something done vs I got something done.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54939/i-had-something-done-vs-i-got-something-done) Also [Does the phrase “to get something done” have different meanings?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159016/does-the-phrase-to-get-something-done-have-different-meanings)

Comment: Try "I had the barber cut my hair" or "I got the barber to cut my hair" or "I went to the barber's to have my hair cut".